# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument while opening a .txt file

Tags: python-3.7, oserror

So I am writing a code which will open .txt file and we can either add data into the file or retrieve the data in the file.
Whenever I am running the following code, I get the error which I mentioned above in the title. Can someone please help me and tell me how to correct the error.
I am running this code in Python 3.7.6 IDLE.

CODE:

f1=open("‪C:\ADITYA\new.txt")

ERROR:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aC:\ADITYA\new.txt'

Comment: You have a stray character [\u202a](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) in your path name.

Comment: can you tell me what to do to remove the error

Comment: No idea hot that got there, copy & pasted in a bidirectional environment perhaps? If you delete the string and rewrite it by hand (keyboard), it should work.

Comment: thanks bro. the 2nd option of rewriting the file path through keyboard worked.